# How to mock static variable and builder in a class with Spock?

Tags: java, groovy, junit, spock

```
public class MyLogger {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "application.version")
    String appVersion;

    public static final LogContext logContext = LogContext.createLogContext();

    public void logIt() {
        logContext.eventBuilder(CommonTemplates.FAILED)
                .withObject("Token")
                .withReason("Did not work!")
                .withDeviceVersion(appVersion)
                .build()
                .logError(true);
    }
```

I need to mock the static variable and the builder using spock.
The point of the test should be to check if the builder was called with Object("Token") and Reason("Did not work")

```
  .withObject("Token")
                .withReason("Did not work!")
```

How can I do that with Spock ?

Answer (score 0):

Without extra tools like Mockito or Sarek, you cannot mock static methods in Spock. I suggest to refactor your code for better testability and refrain from using static methods. Maybe you rather want to use a singleton pattern with lazy instantiation or some other means to actually inject a `LogContext` instance which then you can normally mock and stub.